# Jest sort results by name

Tags: java, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-jest

I have a **Person** index in my ElasticSearch database i get all the persons via this method:

```
public List<Person> findAll() {
    SearchResult result = null;
    SearchSourceBuilder searchSourceBuilder = new SearchSourceBuilder();
    searchSourceBuilder.query(QueryBuilders.matchAllQuery());
    Search search = new Search.Builder(searchSourceBuilder.toString()).addIndex(PERSON_INDEX_NAME)
            .addType(PERSON_TYPE_NAME).build();
    try {
        result = client.execute(search);
    } catch (IOException e) {
    }
    List<SearchResult.Hit<Person, Void>> hits = result.getHits(Person.class);
    return hits.stream().map(this::getPerson).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

but i want to get the results sorted alphabetically by name (**person** has String id and String name) but i cant figure out how.
any help is apreciated

Comment: this answer might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42261521/how-to-sort-elasticsearch-results-using-jest/42265028#42265028

Comment: that other question (which i just noticed is mine too xDDD) works because the Long Id, this sort being done by Name (String) doesnt work :c

Comment: And you can't sort by name because your name field is analyzed, right? You probably need to create another sub-field of the name field just for sorting then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well.

i took the list given by ES and ordered it using the Collections sort method

Comment: That won't correctly sort your results, but only the first ten results you're receiving from ES.

Comment: uh? why only the first ten?

Comment: Because you have no size in your query and by default ES only returns the first ten results sorted by score. You need to do some reading: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-from-size.html ;-)

Answer (score 1):

What type is your name field?

The problem may be that ElasticSearch is splitting the name up into words, and then it can sort on any word. Which can give some pretty random looking results (e.g. the name "Zachary A. Zincstein" would come out highly, because it contains an "A").

A solution is to have a 2nd field, where you set type `keyword` in the mapping, and sort on that.

Comment: thanks for your answer, i finished my work on that project and was moved to another, if i remember correctly we changed the fields in the DB to "Not Analyzed" to make ES return the values already sorted.